# Improve rendering performance of animated image in browser

Tags: html, css, animation, blazor, skiasharp

I'm experimenting with different ways of rendering image in a browser. The idea is to create custom HTML element capable of displaying a set of images or frames as a continuous animation. The images will be generated on the server side and streamed to the browser client. The easiest way seems to be using `img` tag consistently updates its `src` attribute. For this, I subscribe to `onload` event and once image is loaded, I update image URL with random timestamp and it automatically sends new request creating infinite loop that looks like an animation. The solution is pretty simple and working, but affects CPU performance and doesn't use any GPU acceleration.

**Controller used as an image source**

```
[ApiController]
public class StreamController : ControllerBase
{
  [Route("/source")]
  public ActionResult Get()
  {
    var o = new Random();
    var pos = o.Next(50, 150);
    var map = new SKBitmap(250, 250);
    var canvas = new SKCanvas(map);
    var paint = new SKPaint
    {
      Color = SKColors.Black,
      Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
      FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High
    };

    canvas.DrawCircle(pos, pos, 20, paint);

    var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(map);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100).SaveTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
  }
}
```

**HTML page**

```
@page "/"

<!-- Solution #1 : SRC attribute -->

<img 
  width="250" 
  height="250" 
  @onload="OnLoad" 
  src="@Source" />

<!-- Solution #2 : background style URL -->

<div 
  style="width: 250px; height: 250px; background: url(@Source)">
</div>

<!-- Solution #3 : SRC of the picture element - does not work -->

<picture style="width: 250px; height: 250px">
  <source srcset="@Source" type="image/png" media="(min-width:250px)">
</picture>

@code 
{
  private Random _generator = new();
  public string Source { get; set; } = "/source";

  public void OnLoad()
  {
    // Animate by creating infinite loop of HTTP calls 
    // updating image source right after loading the previous one

    var uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    var num = _generator.Next();
    var stamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    
    Source = $"/source?{ uid }-{ num }-{ stamp }";
  }
}
```

**The outcome**

Red border is HTML animation. Blue border is CSS background. Picture tag didn't render.

https://youtu.be/gk8Z-LrKxLE

**The questions**

1. Why solution #3 using `picture` element isn't working?
2. Why solution #2 with CSS background is much slower than solution #1 with image tag. Why is it skipping some frames and is not GPU accelerated?
3. Is there a way to decrease load on CPU by changing something in HTML or in the controller, e.g. switching to async streams in controller or convert images to a video stream?

**Update**

Appeared to be there is much bigger issue with refreshing `img` URL. Looks like `FileStreamResult` returned from ASP controller gets locked by an image, so every time I request an image update, like

- /source?1
- /source/2
- /source?3

...browser creates and caches this image and .NET can't release this resource which leads to enormous memory increase.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a series of image, or are you generating new Unique ones on the fly?  It seems to me you should cache at least several images at a time for smoother updates.  At that point, the only data to pass will be updated style strings.  As for #3-- unless they changed something in .net 6.0, I don't recall Blazor implementing an `OnLoad` event.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 `OnLoad` event works for images. The video link shows it. In my script, I added `OnLoad` handler to the image and inside of this handler I update `Source` property that refreshes URL in 3 different tags. In other words, case #3 with `picture` doesn't have it's own `OnLoad`.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Images are generated on the fly. The main purpose is a real-time chart. Start point was taken from here - https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1194#issuecomment-665963796

Comment: I see.  Try changing `void OnLoad` to `async task OnLoad` and if that doesn't work, add a call to `StateHasChanged` in your handler.

Comment: If you want a real-time chart, IMO images are not a good solution.  Blazor works very well with inline **.svg**, so you can add/remove lines, text, and so on just like you would with html markup, and more importantly, vector graphics scale infinitely without pixellating.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I would avoid SVG - https://www.barchart.com/solutions/company/blog/3852318/comparing-html5-canvas-vs-svg-for-charting

Comment: **Blazor** works very well with inline .svg.  Also, being vector-based, it scales very well, allowing things like zoom effects and complex animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution - using Motion JPEG as a source for the `img` or `iframe` tag.   Using `video` tag should be also be possible. Appeared to be most of browsers, if not all of them, support a stream of images sent via HTTP as `multipart/mixed` content where each image in this stream is just a set of bytes separated by some separator.

**Motion JPEG Format**

Sending the following via HTTP will make browser waiting for continuous data from the stream.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--SomeBoundary\r\n
```

The server side producing images should keep the stream open, e.g. using infinite loop. This loop will be producing new images, converting them to appropriate format like JPEG, or even better optimized WEBP, and sending them to the HTTP stream as a set of bytes.

```
--SomeBoundary\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-Length: 100\r\n\r\n 
<Image-Bytes-Go-Here>
\r\n
```

As a result, to show a video that consists of 3 frames, the resulting HTTP response would look like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--SomeBoundary\r\n

--SomeBoundary\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-Length: 100\r\n\r\n 
<Image-Bytes-Go-Here>\r\n

--SomeBoundary\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-Length: 100\r\n\r\n 
<Image-Bytes-Go-Here>\r\n

--SomeBoundary\r\n
Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
Content-Length: 100\r\n\r\n 
<Image-Bytes-Go-Here>\r\n
```

**Optimization**

- [Simple shapes](https://css-tricks.com/css-charts-grid-custom-properties/) could be drawn with pure [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344125/437393)
- Rendering of the main view with lots of dynamic shapes is better done with `SkiaSharp` canvas
- Text rendering in SkiSharp is [somewhat slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163782/why-is-canvas-drawtext-slower-when-the-text-is-not-drawn-entirely-within-the-vie). SVG or plain HTML may be the best option here

**Memory leaks**

The next issue is consistently increasing amount of memory when HTTP stream with images is being requested by `img` tag via HTTP.

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/stream" />
```

Surprisingly, simply replacing `img` tag with `iframe` solves the issue with memory leaks, most probably because frames and browser windows don't cache images as aggressively as `img` tag or at least this cache is being cleaned up more efficiently.

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1/stream" />
```

Links explaining this concept with examples.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG
- https://blog.green.web.za/2019/11/23/mjpeg-in-asp-net-core.html
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server

Real-time charting app implemented as reusable Blazor control.

- https://github.com/Indemos/Canvas-V3